# Can't style element correctly in if/else codeblock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have some data from dummy back-end for example:

```
[
 {
  "title": "title title 0",
  "date": "22/09/2015",
  "author": "author00",
  "langs": [
   "react",
   "javascript"
   ]
 },
 {
 "title": "title 1",
 "date": "09/11/2012",
 "author": "author188",
 "langs": [
 "angular",
 "vue"
   ]
 }],
```

I try to stylize "langs" array by it's first element, example:

```
const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
      if (post.tags[0].startsWith("react")){
        post.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
      }
```

I think 'if' statement is correct but I don't know what to try in codeblock.
when I try to log in console somewhat it is ok.
but many things on this case depends on what is the first [0] element in the array...

for example, if first element contains 'angular' in cideblock many style options must be rearanged on red color, and when it contains 'react' the dominant style color in every case must be a blue color. 
can you advice me generally what is the best solution for changing styles of lots of things with if/else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a color map that defines colors for code tags like this:

```
const colorMap = { 'react': 'red', 'angular': 'blue' };
```

then use it like this:

```
const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
      const tag = post.tags[0];
      const color = colorMap[tag];
      post.style.backgroundColor = color;
});
```